# Is it possible to extract logical page numbers (page labels) from pdfs using JPOD?

Tags: java, pdf

I'd like to extract all annotations of a pdf and their page numbers/labels using `JPOD`.
I know that I get the page number a annotation is added to using [PDAnnotation.getPage()](http://opensource.intarsys.de/JavaDoc/jPod/de/intarsys/pdf/pd/PDAnnotation.html#getPage()) and [PDPage.getNodeIndex()](http://opensource.intarsys.de/JavaDoc/jPod/de/intarsys/pdf/pd/PDPageNode.html#getNodeIndex()).

The problem is that the `NodeIndex` represents only the physical page index running consecutively starting from 0. But the logical page label could differ from that index (e.g. page index 5 has a label called ii or 3 or 'cover') and I'd like to extract the corresponding label, too.
I didn't find information on that browsing the [documentation](http://opensource.intarsys.de/JavaDoc/jPod/overview-summary.html):

So, is it possible to extract that information from a pdf using jpod and how do I achieve that?

Additional information: http://pdf.editme.com/pdfua-PageLabels

Comment: Individual pages don't have a label. The `/PageLabels` object is in `/Catalog`, so you need to find and read that. It is a composite object; you will want to read the `/Nums` array, which indeed indexes pages starting at 0. See **12.4.2 Page Labels** in ISO PDF 32000-1:2008.

Comment: "Individual pages don't have a label." I knew that, but I was hoping that `JPOD` provides a class or function(s) which already implement searching for the corresponding label

Comment: No, there's no utility that gives you the page labels for a given page index. Page label implementation is quite incomplete.